# iOS7 UITableView Y position grayed out?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7

I have a UITableView that was positioned correctly in iOS6, but in iOS7 the Y position is set at 64px and is grayed out so I can't set it to 0px? See image below.

Why is it grayed out and how do I change it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a `UITableViewController`?  You can't update the size of a top level view controller view as it fills the available space.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: No the image shows Y=64 and that is for the UITableView.

Comment: Have you checked the settings under Attributes Inspector? Or the auto layout box under File Inspector.

Comment: Yes and Yes. Why would Y be grayed out ever?